# EditText setOnCreateContextMenuListener handle result

Tags: android

I have set `setOnCreateContextMenuListener` to edittext. `onCreateContextMenu` method is called user long press on edittext. and it opens context menu with '**done**' and '**copy**' options.

But my question is how can I handle when user select done option or copy options?

Can I get any event when user click on done button or copy button. so I can get selected text via clip manager?

```
edit.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            Log.i("TAG", "onCreateContextMenu");//it is printing while context menu is created.

        }
    });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`onContextItemSelected` is the event you should use. but it has no `View` argument to access selected item. Here is a trick to access to selected `View`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    protected View selectedView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);
                registerForContextMenu(lv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {
        this.selectedView = v;
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);            
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        switch(item.getId())
        {
            case R.id.Context_Edit:
                // access to view with this.selectedView
                break;

            case R.id.Context_Delete:
                // access to view with this.selectedView
                break;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your both button event like following example

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity 
 {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);
                registerForContextMenu(lv);
        }
 }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        if (v.getId() == R.id.lv1) 
        {
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Select Action");
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit");
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        if(item.getTitle() == "Edit")
        {
            // do something
        }
        if(item.getTitle() == "Delete")
        {
            // do something
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks 4 replay, I have print log like this. ---@Override
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  Log.i("TAG", "onContextItemSelected");--- but it doesn't print. it means method is not invoking.

Comment: but u haven't take button event see my answer carefully bro. @nil

Comment: yes. but if onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) called then it will go to next line. so I have printed log at the first line when mehod invoke.

Comment: this option menu can't log anything because you haven't take any action event. @nil

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43514/discussion-between-andrain-and-nil)

Comment: join me at discussion chat @nil

Answer (score 0):

You must to override the onLongClick of the editText and setting one CAB. This is example:

```
    private ActionMode.Callback action = new ActionMode.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.copy){
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
                Log.i("CAB",String.valueOf(clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText()));
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    private EditText edtText;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 


        edtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtText1);

        registerForContextMenu(edtText);
        edtText.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                ((EditText)v).setTextIsSelectable(true);                
                ((EditText)v).setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(action);
                return false;
            }
        });  

    }
```